# How to make bootstrap glyphicon circle shape?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make bootstrap glyphicon round shape i added border radius to class `glyhphicon-menu` but i dont see anything happening , Any idea how to make it happen using bootstrap or css ?

main.html

```
<span  type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list glyhphicon-menu" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" id="treelist"></span>
```

main.css

```
.glyphicon.glyhphicon-menu {
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Try an inspect element and see if there is a .glyphicon.glyphicon-menu:before and try changing it there.

Comment: `.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu:before` is not there and i changed in chrome but no result, i see `font size` property changed.

Comment: Does the span have a background-color or border applied to it?

Comment: have you tried to set element as display: inline-block; ?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `overflow:hidden` so that it clips the text that goes outside the border.

```css
.glyphicon.glyhphicon-menu {
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span  type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list glyhphicon-menu" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" id="treelist"></span>
```